# Need to automate IE with drop down menu using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, ie-automation

I want to automate a site having drop down menu named 'Timesheet' and then click on the Menu item 'Project' which is 3rd in the list.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault()" title="Timesheet" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Timesheet <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a ui-sref="AddTime" title="Add time" href="/Timesheet/AddTime/">Add time</a></li>
                            <li><a ui-sref="ApproveTime" title="Approve time" href="/Timesheet/ApproveTime">Approve time</a></li>
                            <li><a ui-sref="Projects" title="Projects" href="/Timesheet/Admin/Projects">Projects</a></li>
                            <li><a ui-sref="BudgetCode" title="Budget Code" href="/Timesheet/Admin/BudgetCode">Budget Code</a></li>
                            <li><a ui-sref="WorkCode" title="Work Code" href="/Timesheet/Admin/WorkCode">Work Code</a></li>
                            <li><a ui-sref="Functions" title="Functions" href="/Timesheet/Admin/Functions">Functions</a></li>
                            <li><a ui-sref="WorkStreams" title="Work Streams" href="/Timesheet/Admin/WorkStreams">Work Streams</a></li>
                            <li><a ui-sref="EmployeeResource" title="Employees" href="/Timesheet/Admin/EmployeeResource">Employees</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
```

VBA code:
Private Sub IE_Test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim ElementCol As Object

```
' Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'IE.Visible = False

IE.Navigate "http://st-toss/"

' Wait while IE loading...
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

IE.Visible = True

Set ElementCol = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu")

ElementCol.Item(2).Click

' Clean up
Set IE = Nothing
Set objElement = Nothing
Set objCollection = Nothing

Application.StatusBar = ""
```

End Sub

I have tried selecting by classname/tagname but I have been getting the same error Automation error/Unspecified error once i did not add any break point. And once i put the breakpoint on the get method error message says object invoked disconnected from client.

Please suggest how can i get through this.

[image: Refrences for VBA]

Answer (score 0):

ElementCol is a collection of elements in the class "dropdown-menu".  (You created this collection when you set getElementsByClassName.  Notice that "Elements" is plural.)

How many elements are there in that class, and which one is the one you need?
If this is the only element in that class, then you would refer to it by :

```
elementCol(0).selectedIndex = 2
```

or something similar.